# Iceweasel can't read courses on Coursera

Tags: firefox

When logged in, I can see courses I enrolled. But when I click https://www.coursera.org/courses, whether logged in or not, I always get "No results". Yet Coursera works fine with my chromium.

Does this have anything to do with my settings?
PS: I already enabled Javascript of Iceweasel.

Don't really know what info else I should provide....Just so weird....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to 24.0 (currently on unstable) fixes this. My 17.0 didn't work either.

Comment: Brilliant! Do you know the reason?